# SQL / sum on different date ranges with other conditions

Tags: sql, oracle, sum

I have the following code:

```
SELECT 

day
,product_id
,product_name
,quantity_on_hand
,inventory_condition

FROM
(
SELECT 
table1.product_id as product_id
,table1.product_name as product_name

FROM table1

WHERE
product_id = XXXX
)product_table

,

(
SELECT
table2.day as day
,table2.product_id as inv_product_id
,inventory_condition
,sum( table2.quantity) AS quantity_on_hand

 FROM table2
WHERE 
table2.day = TO_DATE('{RUN_DATE_YYYY/MM/DD}', 'YYYY/MM/DD') 

AND table2.inventory_condition = XXX

GROUP BY
 table2.day
,table2.product_id
,inventory_conditio
) inv


WHERE
product_id = inv.product_id
```

this code works great if I want to extract the data for a single day. But I want to extract the data for 3 different days in the same query. I've tried to use a OR() on my condition on table2.day but it will give me the sum of the data for the 3 days all together. I've also tried to do

```
Sum() over (Partition by table2.day)
```

But i'm not sure how to use the syntax.

tahks a lot for your help

Comment: why will it "give you the sum for the 3 days all together"? You've got a group by table2.day in there, so it should group the sum by day as well as by the product_id and inventory_condition. What makes you think it doesn't?

Comment: (I'd personally amend the where clause to `where table2.day in (date1, date2, date3)`)

Comment: I suggest you try something simple first. Here is the partition [sintaxis](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions163.htm)

Comment: You're grouping by day, so `sum` would aggregate over each day and give you three rows of data (or up to three rows per product_id/inventory_condition). This also has an ambiguous reference to product_id in the outer query, which should error - not sure why you're using inline views here at all, which is a side issue but makes your code overly complicated. What code did you actually try with the three days? Including data, expected and actual results is always helpful too.

Comment: Please give example input data, the results you get and the results you expect.  Show usual behaviour and corner case behaviour.  Normal debugging and testing techniques.  This may also help you improve your question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: hi thanks for your suggestions the group by is indeed working well with the three dates in the where clause with the suggested format and gives me the expected result (summed data for each of the three dates)